# How to get Imageview location in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview

I want to crop picture got from `FrameLayout(@+id/previewFrame)` as overlapped `ImageView(@+id/guide_line_view)` yellow guide line boundary.

[image: Guide Line Image]

I got ImageView location and cropped image what I got from previewFrame camera along the border of ImageView.

But imageview location is different from where it is visible, so cropped image not coincide with what I expect

`ImageView(@+id/guide_line_view)` is rectangle border xml like this

What's wrong with my crop. I searched stackoverflow, google 7 hours, but nothing helps.

**@drawable/guide_line.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#FFFF00"
        android:dashGap="8dp"
        android:dashWidth="30dp"/>
    <corners android:radius="8dp" />
</shape>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2">
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/previewFrame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        </FrameLayout>

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/guide_line_view"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="100dp"
                android:background="@drawable/guide_line"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Bring Here"
                android:textColor="#FFFF00"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/guide_line_view"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.207" />
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </FrameLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/take"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="takePicture"
            tools:ignore="ButtonStyle" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/close"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="close"
            tools:ignore="ButtonStyle" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**To get imageview location**

below guide variable asserted as global int

And I calculate at `onWindowFocusChanged`.

```
guide_left = imageview.getLeft();
guide_top = imageview.getTop();
guide_width = imageview.getWidth();
guide_height = imageview.getHeight();
```

**I've tried this as well. And so on.**

```
int[] guide_location = new int[2];

imageview.getLocationOnScreen(guide_location);
int guide_left = guide_location[0];
int guide_top = guide_location[1];
```

**crop bitmap**

```
public void takePicture() {
        cameraView.capture(new Camera.PictureCallback(){
            public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera){
                try {
                    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
                    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
                    matrix.postRotate(90);
                    Bitmap r_bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);


                    // crop the image
                    Bitmap cropped_bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(r_bitmap, guide_left, guide_top, guide_width, guide_height);
```

I save `cropped_bitmap` and check it is correct, but not.

Comment: Is “imageview.getLocationOnScreen” in your “oncreate()”? Drawing views in “oncreate()” is not fully complete.so maybe you can "postDelayed" call "getLocationOnScreen".

Comment: @hikari I calculate at `onWindowFocusChanged`. And when I debug it, values are not zero.

Comment: maybe you need postDelayed call. imageview.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                    imageview.getLocationOnScreen(guide_location);
            }
        },500);

Comment: @hikari result is same before

Comment: Rect viewRect = new Rect(); 
imageview.getGlobalVisibleRect(viewRect);viewRect.left;viewRect.top;

Comment: @hikari Result is same before. All of thing crop same area, but not correct with guide line. I want location **Yellow guide line area**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supposed you take a picture in resolution `4096×2160` , and then set in previewFrame,
but if your device only have `1920x1080` resolution, the previewFrame only measure size in `1920x1080`

As post you want to crop the specified rect from the `orgin picture` , you need to scale the `crop ratio` up
from `1920x1080 to 4096x2160`

--- Try below ---

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.postRotate(90);
Bitmap r_bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);

// scaled ratio
float ratio = 1f * bitmap.getWidth() / previewFrame.width;

// crop the image
Bitmap cropped_bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(r_bitmap,
    (int) (guide_left * ratio),
    (int) (guide_top * ratio),
    (int) (guide_width * ratio), 
    (int) (guide_height * ratio));
```

Comment: This is just an idea, maybe you need to scale both `width` and `height` ratio up.

Comment: `float ratio = 1f * bitmap.getWidth() / previewFrame.width;` Also working different as screen resolution, and not correct. Is there other suitable ratio value?

Comment: I found solution! `createScaledBitmap` works, not `createBitmap` !

Comment: That's great! And sorry about I had no time to test this for you.